# How can I test unit test my jQuery-based code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing

I have following code in a file named index.js. I want to test some functions in it `add`, `print` being the prime one.

```
(function($){
  "use strict";

  $(function(){

    var add = function(a, b){
    // ...
      },
    print = function(str){
    // ...
      },
      setup = function(){
    // ...
      },
      init = function(){
    // ...
      };

      setup();
      init();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

How can I do so?
Does this way of coding add any security on client side? All I have is code that runs on the client side. No server involvement what-so-ever.

I tried :

```
var outerObj = (function(greet){
    var innerObj = (function(){
        return {test: function(){ console.log(greet); }}
    })();
    return innerObj;
})("hi");

outerObj.test();
```

but, in my case, `innerObj` line has a `$` on the right hand of equal sign, making console yell error that shouts **$(...) is not a function**. 
Which I agree, it's an array of single document object.

Check out `var a = (function(){ var val = $(function(){return 10;})(); })();` in any jquery enabled web-page's console, for the error.

Even if I ditch outer shell and bring `$(function() {});` out. How am I gonna test that?

It's still an object, still an error.

What kind of testing can I perform, unit, bdd, etc. and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite see what pattern you're using here - it seems like a bit of an anti-pattern. It's not testable, and doesn't expose any behaviour for real world use. I'd highly recommend reading (or at least skimming) [Javascript Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/) by Addy Osmani, available for free.

For Unit Testing, I've always found a happy midpoint between the simple constructor pattern and revealing module pattern easiest to work with.

```
var x = function($){
"use strict";

  var add = function(a, b){
     alert('add');
    },
    print = function(str){
     return 1;
    },
    setup = function(){
      alert('setup');
    },
    init = function(){
      alert('init');
    };

  init();
  setup();

  return {
      add: add,
      print: print
  };
};

var y = new x(jQuery);
```

In the above example, `y` will have the `add` and `print` methods available. Check out a sample test on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/x7y8ucq7/).

As a side note, I've recently been using the excellent [QUnit framework](https://qunitjs.com/) for setting up and running my JS Unit Tests. It's by the jQuery Team, so you know it's gonna be good ;).
I'd also suggest checking out [BlanketJS](http://blanketjs.org/) for reporting on coverage, and [qunit-parameterize](https://github.com/AStepaniuk/qunit-parameterize) for setting up multiple test cases.

For what its worth, BDD isn't a 'test type', but a way of working. For what tests you should have - Unit Tests and Integration Tests are the most important 2, IMO. I use QUnit for Unit Tests, and Selenium with NUnit for Integration Testing.